# Advance a git branch to selected commit remotely without checking out

Tags: git

I am having a branch `lagging` which is some commits behind `current`.

Let's say, `current` is ahead by commits `bbb` and `ccc`.

Now from a separate client which does NOT have the whole git history, I would like to advance the `lagging` branch and fast-forward it to `bbb`.

I tried this

```
git push --force "$repourl" "bbb:lagging"
```

This push is meant to push commit `bbb` to branch `lagging`. The HEAD of the branch is an ancestor of commit `bbb`, so I am not at all concerned about using a force push.

However, this results in

> fatal: bad object bbb

When I first run a fetch, however, it works.

```
git fetch --depth=1 "$repourl" "bbb"
git push --force "$repourl" "bbb:lagging"
```

The fetch takes a bit of time, as it seems to be downloading the whole repo at this commit. I would like to avoid that.

Is there a way to perform the purely remote push without a fetch first? Or is there a way to make the fetch more lightweight?

**EDIT**: The context of this is a job running on CI. At the end of the task, I want to advance another branch with the commit which just passed all tests. The job running the tests only has a shallow clone, and it's using a mirror git repository.

Comment: `The purely remote push` looks like a malicious attack. A workaround is to run a server (like a Django app) on the machine hosting the remote repository, so that you can send a request to the server. The request calls a command like `git -C /path/to/repo update-ref refs/heads/lagging bbb` to update the branch.

Comment: @ElpieKay: “The purely remote push looks like a malicious attack”? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I am also curious. The use case, in case you were wondering, is fast-forwarding a branch from a CI build. The CI build only has a shallow clone, and for obvious reasons we want the operation to be as fast as possible.